# ways to run external shell commands in sbt

Tags: sbt

How can I run external shell commands once I am in `sbt` interactive shell?

That is, after I type `sbt` and see the prompt showing up, how can I do things like `ls`, or `cd` etc.? There should be a way to do this, correct?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a bash script as sbt task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996437/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-as-sbt-task)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community/Community-Plugins.html is a list of SBT plugins.

A plugin for your purpose can be https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh .