# How to execute a bash script as sbt task?

Tags: sbt

I want to automatically build documentation for my Java Play 2.3 application.
At the moment, I use a Makefile to generate images from `*.dot`files and combine Markdown sources together into Html/PDF:

```
dot diagram1.dot -Tpdf -o diagram1.pdf
dot diagram2.dot -Tpdf -o diagram2.pdf
pandoc doc1.markdown -o doc1.pdf
# ...
```

Now I want to run these simple bash commands directly from SBT. 
What's the best way to do this?

I found some [SBT Documentation plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Community-Plugins.html#Documentation+plugins) in the SBT reference, but nothing to run a simple shell script.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can find some answers in [External Processes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html) in the official documentation of sbt, e.g.

> To run an external command, follow it with an exclamation mark !:
>
> ```
>  "find project -name *.jar" !
> ```

Don't forget to use `import scala.sys.process._` so `!` can be resolved as a method of `String`.

Do the following in activator console (*aka* sbt shell) to execute `yourshell.sh` - mind the `eval` command and the quotes around the name of the script:

```
eval "yourshell.sh" !
```

To have it available as a task add the following to `build.sbt` of your project:

```
lazy val execScript = taskKey[Unit]("Execute the shell script")

execScript := {
  "yourshell.sh" !
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the following command which contains double quotes and it fails to execute. It just prints whatever is within the double quotes.
`"mongo test -eval \"db.dropDatabase()\"" !`

This is an issue for every command containing quotes.

Comment: Can you use triple quotes instead?

Comment: Is it possible to honour the response code of the script as well as log the complete output

Answer (score 37):

We had the requirement to execute some npm scripts as sbt task and let the build fail if one of the npm scripts fails. Took me some time to find a way to create a Task that works on Windows and Unix. And so here is what I came up with.

```
lazy val buildFrontend = taskKey[Unit]("Execute frontend scripts")

buildFrontend := {
      val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
      val shell: Seq[String] = if (sys.props("os.name").contains("Windows")) Seq("cmd", "/c") else Seq("bash", "-c")
      val npmInstall: Seq[String] = shell :+ "npm install"
      val npmTest: Seq[String] = shell :+    "npm run test"
      val npmLint: Seq[String] = shell :+    "npm run lint"
      val npmBuild: Seq[String] = shell :+   "npm run build"
      s.log.info("building frontend...")
      if((npmInstall #&& npmTest #&& npmLint #&& npmBuild !) == 0) {
        s.log.success("frontend build successful!")
      } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("frontend build failed!")
      }
},
(run in Compile) <<= (run in Compile).dependsOn(buildFrontend)
```