# SBT plugin to create image from a plain Docker text file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin, sbt-docker

I want to build an image for a plain Dockerfile text, Is there an SBT plugin that will let me specify my own docker file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see a need for a plugin here. The simplest way is to just create a sbt task which calls docker process in the shell. Doing so in sbt is quite simple, take a look at this answer: [How to execute a bash script as sbt task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996437/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-as-sbt-task)

Something like this:

```scala
lazy val yourDockerTask = taskKey[Unit]("Runs docker build")

yourDockerTask := {
  "docker build ." !
}
```

Then you can call the task you just created from the sbt shell.

Comment: Note that you can specify a custom Dockerfile name using `docker build -f your_docker_file .`